# How to add live javascript interaction with an object from the database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a restaurant ordering website. The idea is there's a menu and there's a "My order" bar on the right. The meals from the menu are database objects. I want to be able to click the "add" button on the object and it should appear in the "my order" bar immediately without refreshing the page. I have no idea how to implement it so fat. Could you guys offer me any ideas? Desirable technologies are Rails and JavaScript. Thanks.

Comment: Use Rails ajax "remote: true" option.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: "database objects" assumes a back-end technology stack has been setup. Lookup solution for doing similar things in the backend technology.

Comment: If I use remote:true how do I "transfer" object info to the front end?

Comment: You need a Rails tutorial.

Comment: @Eric I agree :) What topic exactly should I read about to learn how to it?

Comment: I suggest starting at the beginning.

Comment: @Eric I would love to but I have very little time on my hands at the moment. Will do it later for sure but now I need a solution asap

Answer (score 0):

You want to use AJAX to asynchronously call the database and handle the response. You can do this a number of ways. Popular ways in Rails include JQuery and/or Rails's UJS. Modern options include Turbolinks 3. They all operate on the same principles.

Any way you do it, you'll make a call to a controller (your "endpoint") to retrieve data from the db and return a response, probably a JSON object or maybe even an html partial. You'll handle that response in your front end code.

Here's a fairly old but good tutorial on the basics. http://railscasts.com/episodes/136-jquery-ajax-revised